# Javascript - return Console/DOM output as a single JSON output

Tags: javascript, json, console, output, onkeyup

In my page, I've added an `onkeyup` event in order to get the keys that have been *pressed* in my `input`.

I get the results in my console, but I need to output all the *events* as a single `JSON` output and `return` it.

*I'm new in `JS`and any help is appreciated*

**PS:** For some reason my snippet doesn't work here, but in my `index.html` I can see the event output fine.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    const myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
    myInput.onkeyup = function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="myInput">
```

The screenshot below is what I get in return:
[image]

*Current output*:

```
{isTrusted: true, key: "a", code: "KeyA", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
{isTrusted: true, key: "s", code: "KeyS", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
{isTrusted: true, key: "d", code: "KeyD", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
{isTrusted: true, key: "a", code: "KeyA", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
{isTrusted: true, key: "s", code: "KeyS", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
{isTrusted: true, key: "d", code: "KeyD", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
{isTrusted: true, key: "a", code: "KeyA", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
{isTrusted: true, key: "s", code: "KeyS", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
{isTrusted: true, key: "d", code: "KeyD", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
```

And what I'm looking for is to be able to *assign* this to a variable, like `var json` and output would be something as:

```
{
    "onkeyup":
        "{isTrusted: true, key: "a", code: "KeyA", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
        {isTrusted: true, key: "s", code: "KeyS", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
        {isTrusted: true, key: "d", code: "KeyD", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
        {isTrusted: true, key: "a", code: "KeyA", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
        {isTrusted: true, key: "s", code: "KeyS", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
        {isTrusted: true, key: "d", code: "KeyD", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
        {isTrusted: true, key: "a", code: "KeyA", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
        {isTrusted: true, key: "s", code: "KeyS", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
        {isTrusted: true, key: "d", code: "KeyD", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}"
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *output all the events as a single JSON output and return it.* What sort of output? Return to what? Can you give an example?

Comment: `var a = [];  a.push(e)`

Comment: @sa_n__u Thanks, I did that at first, but still comes as single and not as the output example I added in the question

Comment: @Rubioli `var a = {'onKeyup':[]}; a.onKeyup.push(e)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first things first:

The output sample you gave us **is not valid in any JSON specification** and don't evaluate as a object in JavaScript (because of the wrong use of quotes).

What you want instead is an object with a property "onkeyup" (the name of event handled) that holds an array of objects (in your case, the ocurrences of this event).

```
let obj = { onkeyup: [] };

window.onload = function() {
    const myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');

    myInput.onkeyup = function(e) {
        obj.onkeyup.push(e);
        console.log( obj );
    }

}
```

[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7v1G.png)

This might solve your problem by having and object with the structure desired that you can actually update and use as you want further on your code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
    // new Array to store events
    let events = []
    window.onload = function() {
        const myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
        myInput.onkeyup = function(e) {
            //console.log(e);
            //Push events into array
            events.push(e)
            // Log events array
            console.log({events})
        }
    }
<input type="text" value="" id="myInput">
```